# (Python) Error when trying to make Bar Graph "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to have "inp == 3:" make a bar graph with the top 5 populated states that are listed in my code. I keep getting the error which is listed below and can't figure it out. Someone please help.

```
`
if inp == 3:
            
            sorted_states = sorted(
                state, key=lambda i: i['population'], reverse=True)
            fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

            sorted_states_names = []
            sorted_states_populations = []

            for x in sorted_states[:5]:
                sorted_states_names.append(x["state"])
                sorted_states_populations.append(x["population"])

            # creating the bar plot
            plt.bar(sorted_states_names, sorted_states_populations,
                    width=0.4)
            plt.show()
`
```

Error:

```
sorted_states = sorted(state, key=lambda i: i['population'], reverse=True)
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Here is the Entire Code...I updated this because someone commented saying it might be helpful to have the whole code so you can put it in yourself..I was just trying to save time on posting the whole code:

```
`
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

state = []

state.append ( ['Alabama', 'Montgomery', 4887680, 'Camellia'] )
state.append ( ['Alaska', 'Juneau', 735139, 'Forget-Me-Not'] )
state.append ( ['Arizona', 'Phoenix', 7158020, 'Suguaro Catus  
Blossom'] )
state.append ( ['Arkansas', 'Little Rock', 3009730, 'Apple Blossom'] )
state.append ( ['California', 'Sacremento ', 39461600, 'Golden Poppy'] 
)
state.append ( ['Colorado', 'Denver', 5691290, 'Mountain Columbine'] )
state.append ( ['Connecticut', 'Hatford', 3571520, 'Mountain Laurel'] 
)
state.append ( ['Delaware', 'Dover', 965479, 'Peach Blossom'] )
state.append ( ['Florida', 'Tallahassee', 21244300, 'Orange Blossom'] 
)
state.append ( ['Georgia', 'Atlanta', 10511100, 'Cherokee Rose'] )
state.append ( ['Hawaii', 'Honolulu', 1420590, 'Red Hibiscus'] )
state.append ( ['Idaho', 'Boise', 1750540, 'Syringa'] )
state.append ( ['Illinois', 'Springfield', 12723100, 'Violet'] )
state.append ( ['Indiana', 'Indianaplois', 6695500, 'Peony'] )
state.append ( ['Iowa', 'Des Moines', 3148620, 'Wild Rose'] )
state.append ( ['Kansas', 'Topeka', 2911360, 'Sunflower'] )
state.append ( ['Kentucky', 'Frankfort', 4461150, 'Goldenrod'] )
state.append ( ['Louisiana', 'Baton Rouge', 4659690, 'Magnolia'] )
state.append ( ['Maine', 'Augusta', 1339060, 'Pine Cone & Tassel'] )
state.append ( ['Maryland', 'Annapolis', 6035800, 'Black-eyed Susan'] 
)
state.append ( ['Massachusettes', 'Boston', 6882640, 'Mayflower'] )
state.append ( ['Michigan', 'Lansing', 9984070, 'Apple Blossom'] )
state.append ( ['Minniesota', 'St.Paul', 5606250, 'Lady-Slipper'] )
state.append ( ['Mississippi', 'Jackson', 2981020, 'Magnolia'] )
state.append ( ['Missouri', 'Jefferson City', 6121620, 'Hawthorne'] )
state.append ( ['Montana', 'Helena', 1060660, 'Bitterroot'] )
state.append ( ['Nebraska', 'Lincoln', 1925610, 'Goldenrod'] )
state.append ( ['Nevada', 'Carson City', 3027340, 'Sagebrush'] )
state.append ( ['New Hampshire', 'Concord', 1353460, 'Purple Lilac'] )
state.append ( ['New Jersey', 'Trenton', 8886020, 'Violet'] )
state.append ( ['New Mexico', 'Santa Fe', 2092740, 'Yucca'] )
state.append ( ['New York', 'Albany', 19530400, 'Rose'] )
state.append ( ['North Carolina', 'Raleigh', 10381600, 'Flowering    
Dogwood'] )
state.append ( ['North Dakota', 'Bismark', 758080, 'Prairie Rose'] )
state.append ( ['Ohio', 'Columbus', 11676300, 'Scalet Carnation'] )
state.append ( ['Oklahoma', 'Oklahoma City', 3940240, 'Mistletoe'] )
state.append ( ['Oregon', 'Salem', 4181890, 'Oregon Grape'] )
state.append ( ['Pennsylvania', 'Harrisburg', 12800900, 'Mountain   
Laurel'] )
state.append ( ['Rhode Island', 'Providence', 1058290, 'Violet'] )
state.append ( ['South Carolina', 'Columbia', 5084160, 'Yellow 
Jessamine'] )
state.append ( ['South Dakota', 'Pierre', 878698, 'Pasque flower'] )
state.append ( ['Tennessee', 'Nashville', 6771630, 'Iris'] )
state.append ( ['Texas', 'Austin', 28628700, 'Bluebonnet'] )
state.append ( ['Utah', 'Salt Lake City', 3153550, 'Sego Lily'] )
state.append ( ['Vermont', 'Montpelier', 624358, 'Red Clover'] )
state.append ( ['Virginia', 'Richmond', 8501290, 'Dogwood'] )
state.append ( ['Washington', 'Olympia', 7523870, 'Coast 
Rhododendron'] )
state.append ( ['West Virginia', 'Charleston', 1804290, 
'Rhododendron'] )
state.append ( ['Wisconsin', 'Madison', 5807410, 'Wood Violet'] )
state.append ( ['Wyoming', 'Cheyenne', 577601, 'Indian Paintbrush'] )
state.sort()

def showOptions():
print("1. List data and states in order")
print("2. Show a certain state")
print("3. Make a Bar graph with top 5 highest population states")
print("4. Certain state overall population")
print("5. Exit")


while True:
showOptions()
inp = int(input("Choose an option: "))

if inp == 1:
    for state in data:
        for j in state:
            print(j + ":", state[j])
        print()

if inp == 2:
        search = input("Input state you wish to search: ")
        for state in data:
            if state["state"] == search:
                for j in state:
                    print(j + ":", state[j])
                print()
                break

if inp == 3:

            sorted_states = sorted(state, key=lambda i: i[2],    
            reverse=True)
            fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

            sorted_states_names = []
            sorted_states_populations = []

            for x in sorted_states[:5]:
                sorted_states_names.append(x["state"])
                sorted_states_populations.append(x["population"])

            # creating the bar plot
            plt.bar(sorted_states_names, sorted_states_populations,
                    width=0.4)
            plt.show()

if inp == 4:
                state_to_be_modified = input(
                    "Input state to update population: ")
                population = int(
                    input("Input the increase amount: "))
                for state in data:
                    if state["state"] == state_to_be_modified:
                        state["population"] += population
                        break

if inp == 5:
                    print("Thanks you for stopping by")
                    exit(0)
else:
                    print("Invalid input. try another")  


`
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a list not a dict. Try

```
sorted_states = sorted(state, key=lambda i: i[2], reverse=True)
```

Comment: I changed what you said and that worked, now it's giving me this error: sorted_states_names.append(x["state"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: You should take a look into how lists work in python, because you are still trying  to index lists with strings.
```sorted_states_names.append(x[0])
                sorted_states_populations.append(x[3])
```
Instead of passing a string, you need to pass the corresponding index e.g. 0 and 3